# Как вытащить строку из request'a?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax

Мне нужно вытащить из request'a строку, которую я передал сервлету с помощью ajax запроса.
Вот код ajax запроса:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#login-button").click(function(){
            var userPassword = $("input#userPassword").val();
            var userLogin = $("input#userLogin").val();
            var dataString = "log_in " + userLogin + " " + userPassword;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "http://localhost:8181/library/login",
                data: dataString,
                dataType: "text",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Welcome!");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                    alert("Wrong login or password");
                }
            });
        });
    });
```

И мне со стороны сервлета нужно вытащить `dataString`. Как это будет выглядеть? Потому что в следующем ниже коде, `request.getQueryString` всегда получается `null`ом.

```
@Override
public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    SocketConnection.output.println(request.getQueryString());
    String string = SocketConnection.input.readLine();
    if(string.equals("1")) {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("workshop.html");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    } else if(string.equals("2")) {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("library.html");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    } else {
        out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: POST передает данные не в QueryString, а в Form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  data: { login: userLogin, password: userPassword },
  ...

String login = request.getParameter("login");
String password = request.getParameter("password");
```